# what is color block of instruments mean?

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting, instruments

[image]

In this project i using ARC
what is meaning of the red color and yellow and is it memory leak ?

Answer (score 1):

The line of code highlighted red in your screenshot is red because a high percentage of the memory allocated in the method actCallTaxi: is allocated in the highlighted line, 94% of the allocated memory. If you find actCallTaxi: is allocating too much memory, Instruments is alerting you to the source of the high memory allocation by highlighting the line of code red.

The line of code highlighted yellow is yellow because a smaller percentage of memory allocated in actCallTaxi: is allocated in the yellow line. Instruments uses color coding to show the severity of possible problems in your code, with red being more severe than yellow.

The graph for the Leaks instrument isn't showing any leaks so you most likely don't have a problem with memory leaks.